# Can Boost.Geometry be used to convert NAD27 to NAD83?

Tags: boost, gis, boost-geometry

In the Boost.Geometry documentation it is stated that GIS is one of the primary motivations for the library. Are there routines in Boost.Geometry for converting UTM/NAD27/NAD83, and other geographic coordinate systems, or does the design of Boost.Geometry allow the easy implementation of a function which converts between these systems? Examples appreciated, thanks.